# Como recorrer un Collection en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Esta vez tengo una laguna mental y no se que se me esta escapando....

Tengo la siguiente coleccion, anexo imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un modelo llamado Ingreso y otro llamado DetalleIngreso, en la cual en las relaciones tengo de Ingreso a DetalleIngreso y viceversa "Un ingreso tienen muchos detalles de ingreso y muchos detalles de ingreso pertenecen a un ingreso" en mi modelo la relacion es asi:

de ingreso a detalle de ingreso la relacion se llama: detalleIngreso

de detalle de ingreso a ingreso la relacion se llama: ingreso

Bien todo bien hasta alli, el asunto es que estoy haciendo una consulta eloquent a ingreso y la hago asi:

```
$verDatosIngreso=Ingreso::orderBy('id')
        ->with('detalleIngreso')
        ->where('id','=',$id)
        ->get();
```

se supone despues que para poder acceder a "servicio_id" de la relacion detalleIngreso pues debo recorrer el array

```
foreach($verDatosIngreso as $c)
{
  $c->detalleIngreso->servicio_id
}
```

Pero no me esta funcionando, se que me esta faltando algo pero no recuerdo que rayos es.

Espero me puedan aclarar la novatada que estoy cometiendo la verdad no me acuerdo.

Gracias....

Comment: Puedes mostrar el error que tienes porfavor?

Comment: Mucho depende de tu caso de uso. Para qué necesitas recoger la colección? ¿quieres sacar todos los 'service_id' en array/collection?. Por otro lado, como @AlonsoUreña menciona, sería muy útil que muestres el error que te devuelve y también como tienes configurada tus relaciones (código).

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que la relación entre `Ingreso` y `DetalleIngreso` es de uno a muchos:

```
Ingreso 1 ---- m DetalleIngreso
```

Entonces, al acceder a la relación a través de `Ingreso`, el resultado es una colección de objetos.

Si tú tienes una colección de modelos `Ingreso` y quieres acceder a los objetos pertenecientes a la relación `detalleIngreso`, quiere decir que debes acceder a los objetos de una colección (`Ingreso`) de colecciones (`DetalleIngreso`).

No se puede acceder directamente a los atributos de una colección sin recorrerla. Por esta consulta es errónea:

```
$verDatosIngreso = Ingreso::orderBy('id')
    ->with('detalleIngreso')
    ->where('id','=',$id)
    ->get();

foreach($verDatosIngreso as $c)
{
  $c->detalleIngreso->servicio_id //  $c->detalleIngreso es una colección
}
```

La solución sería acceder al arreglo recorriendo la colección de la relación:

```
foreach($verDatosIngreso as $ingreso)
{
    foreach($ingreso->detalleIngreso as $detalle)
    {
      $detalle->servicio_id
      // alguna otra acción
    }
}
```

Por otro lado, dado que estamos trabajando con colecciones, podrías utilizar la función `each()` que es propia de las colecciones:

```
$verDatosIngreso = Ingreso::orderBy('id')
        ->with('detalleIngreso')
        ->where('id', '=', $id)
        ->get()
        ->each(function ($ingreso) {
            $ingreso->detalleIngreso->each(function ($detalle) {
                $detalle->servicio_id;
                // alguna otra acción
            });
        });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo... sabia que tenia que recorrer dos veces la colección el asunto es que no recordaba como. Me has ayudado con tu explicacion gracias...

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
@foreach($verDatosIngreso as $c)  
    {{$c['detalleIngreso']->servicio_id}}  
@endforeach
```

Estoy seguro que aquí entras a detalle de ingreso

```
@foreach($verDatosIngreso as $c)  
    {{$c['detalleIngreso']}}  
@endforeach
```

Pero como es una colección dentro de otra colección seria de seguir probando

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método propio [`each`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-each) de las Colecciones de [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) y luego volver a iterar la relación, más o menos de la siguiente manera:

```
$verDatosIngreso->each(function ($datoIngreso, $indice) {
    $datoIngreso->detalleIngreso->each(function ($detale, $subIndice) {
        $detalle->servicio_id;
    });
});
```